# Real function, satisfying $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}f(x_0)<1+f^2(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $ f(x):[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $b-a\geq 4$ and $f(x)$  is  differentiable in every point of interval $(a,b)$.

How can I prove that there exists $ x_0\in (a,b)$ , satisfying $$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}f(x_0)<1+f^2(x_0).$$

I have no idea how to do it((

Comment: What is $f^2(x_0)$ here?  $f(f(x_0))$ or $[f(x_0)]^2$?

Comment: $f^2(x_0) =[f(x_0)]^2$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $\exists \xi \in (a,b):f'(\xi)<1+f^2(\xi)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995383/prove-exists-xi-in-a-bf-xi1f2-xi)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, for pointing out.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the differentiable function $F(x):=\arctan(f(x))$. Then $F(x)\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Moreover, if the desired inequality does not hold, it follows that 
$$F'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{1+f^2(x)}\geq 1$$ 
for all $x\in (a,b)$ which implies
$$\pi=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}>F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b F'(x)\,dx\geq \int_a^b 1\,dx=b-a\geq 4$$
which is a contradiction.